# Trying to extract specific lines of text

Tags: python, powershell

```
        {
            "username": "testuser",
            "votecount": "42",
            "votesclaimed": "0",
            "lastvotetime": "2022-11-04 09:08:29",
            "steamid": "000000000000001"
        },
```

If I have a text file full of these seperated values. I would like to extract just the line that contains the "username": "testuser" and the votecount. It should then output it into a csv with the username and votecount side by side. How could I accomplish this? My outputs have only been so far that all text is output into a single block. Is there any way to achieve this simply? I would like to further add an if statement to the votecount value where as 25>$votecount it would add the letter D by the number taken from votecount. I have that part working but I cannot get it to output how I am wishing.

Ideal output would be:

```
testuser 42D
testuser2 30D
testuser3 24
```

Answer (score 1):

It **looks like your input file is a *JSON* file**, so you should **parse it with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)**, as follows:

```bash
Get-Content -Raw file.json |
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    '{0} {1}{2}' -f $_.username, 
                    $_.votecount, 
                    ('', 'D')[[int] $_.votecount -gt 25]
  }
```

The above produces the desired outputs as shown in your question, with a sample `file.json` file created as follows:

```bash
@'
[
    {
        "username": "testuser",
        "votecount": "42",
        "votesclaimed": "0",
        "lastvotetime": "2022-11-04 09:08:29",
        "steamid": "000000000000001"
    },
    {
        "username": "testuser2",
        "votecount": "30",
        "votesclaimed": "0",
        "lastvotetime": "2022-11-04 09:08:29",
        "steamid": "000000000000001"
    },
    {
        "username": "testuser3",
        "votecount": "24",
        "votesclaimed": "0",
        "lastvotetime": "2022-11-04 09:08:29",
        "steamid": "000000000000001"
    }
]
'@ > file.json
```

---

To **export to a CSV file**, modify the above to output an *object* with the desired *properties*, which you can then pass to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv); e.g.:

```bash
Get-Content -Raw file.json |
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobject] @{
       UserName = $_.username
       VoteCount = '{0}{1}' -f $_.votecount, ('', 'D')[[int] $_.votecount -gt 25]
    }
  } |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 out.csv
```

With the sample JSON, the above creates `out.csv` with the following content:

```
"UserName","VoteCount"
"testuser","42D"
"testuser2","30D"
"testuser3","24"
```

Comment: Can I make it combine like objects that already exist? say I do this weekly and want it to add the count based on the username. How would that look? Take the new numbers weekly from the file I have, then make it output and combine maybe? That might be a little crazy.. I don't know how that would be scripted.

Comment: @TrevorMason, this answer addresses your question as asked. If you have follow-up questions please create a new question post.